# Как конвертировать массив в текст?

Tags: php, массивы

Имеется такой массив с подмассивами:

```
[0] =>
[
  ["key"] => "Max"
  ["value"] => "F."
  ["header"] => "test"
],
[1] =>
[
  ["key"] => "Robert"
  ["value"] => "M."
  ["header"] => "test2"
],
[2] =>
[
  ["key"] => "John"
  ["value"] => "S."
  ["header"] => "test"
]
```

Как мне ее сконвертировать в такой вид на PHP?

```
test
  Max: F.
  John: S.

test2
  Robert: M.
```

Удалось сделать что-то подобное, но получается костыльно :(

Comment: откуда берутся массивы?

Comment: из базы данных.

Comment: значит при выборке из базы данных надо хотя бы отсортировать по полю header

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если все идет с БД то проще все сразу и забирать от туда нужным способом

```
//перебираем все возможные header, не повторяясь, получим: test, test2
$pos = mysqli_query($CONNECT, "SELECT DISTINCT header FROM table");
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($pos)) {
//выводим header
echo $row['0'].'</br>';
//показываем все строки из каждого header по отдельности
$sql2 = mysqli_query($CONNECT, "SELECT * FROM table WHERE header = '$row[0]'");
while($row2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql2) ){
echo ' '.$row2['key'].': '.$row2['value'].'</br>'; 
}
echo '</br>';
}
```

не забудь заменить слово table в обоих местах на с вою таблицу и $CONNECT на свое подключение к БД

Answer (score 0):

рекурсивной функцией/итератором, что-то вроде

```
echo print_r($array, true);
```

или

```
$tree = new RecursiveTreeIterator(new RecursiveArrayIterator($array));
foreach ($tree as $value) {
    echo $value . PHP_EOL;
}
```